# How did the PIE root *per- (forward, through) evolve into 'para-', to mean 'contrary to'?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, greek

> [[Etymonline :]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=para-&allowed_in_frame=0) ... before vowels, par-, word-forming element meaning "alongside, beyond; altered; contrary; irregular, abnormal," from Greek ***para-*** from para (prep.) "beside, near, issuing from, against, **contrary to**," from PIE * prea, from root *** *per-*** (1) **"forward, through"** (see [per](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=per&allowed_in_frame=0)).  ...
>
> [[AHI :]](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#IR123200) per<sup>1</sup> ...
>   ... IV. Extended form * *pr̥əā̆*.
>   ...
>   2. para<sup>1</sup>; palfrey, from Greek para, beside, alongside of, beyond.

I don't understand how "forward, through" evolved into one of the meanings of the Greek prefix *para-*, the one which means '**contrary to**'.

Etymonline seems to refer to AHI's particular entry of *** *per-*** labelled by the superscript  1, but nowhere does AHI explain this meaning of **contrary to**. Strangely, AHI designated  *para* with the superscript 1, but AHI only features  *para* once.

Footnote: My research of the etymology of [paradox](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=paradox&searchmode=none)  motivated this question.

Comment: Different dictionaries have different schemes for grouping words and definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can observe the same phenomenon with anti (**ἀντί**), also in Greek which evolves from "in front" to "instead of" and eventually to "against" (more productive in modern languages than in classical Greek).

1. As "in front" in toponymy: Ἀντίπολις => Antibes, Ἀντικύθηρα => Antikythera, etc..
2. As "against": αντίδικος => opponent (same progression and etymology in Latin for *opponent* and for *adversary*).

From "in front" to "against", the semantic path is clear.

Similarly for **παρά**, we progress quite easily from "side by side" to "compared to" and in some cases from "compared to" to "contrary to".

When the object is literally on our side (as in we can *lean on* it, see *s'appuyer*, *appoggiarsi*) then we don’t have an acceptation of "unfavourable".

1. Παρὰ θεοῖς καὶ παρ᾽ ἀνθρώποις => With Gods and men. Favourable.

If instead, the object is **out of place** (in this sense of παρά: not in its right place) then the idea is that of "different from".  This is visible in English in such words as parascience, parapsychology, or even paralinguistics. In classical Greek we have for instance:

2. Παρά μοίραν => Contrary to fate, unfairly. We still have to count with the Moirai but this is probably not a favourable factor.
3. Παράδοξος   => Out of (contrary to) δόξα expectation, opinion

English also uses *beside* to suggest this kind of opposition. Maybe after all this explanation is *beside* the point.

So in conclusion, the intended meaning is not as much 'against' (which would be κατά or ἀντί) as '[unexpectedly] different'.

### Edit

The English word *with* followed a symmetrical/opposite evolution.
(A brief digression: Using "symmetrical" to mean "opposite" is also quite revealing.)
 - In Old English *wið* meant "against" (it still does in *withstand* or *withsay* for instance).  From Proto-Indo-European *wi ("separation").
  - Now *with* means "alongside".
So this time the semantic shift seems to be "separate" => "face to face" => "alongside".
For instance if you pit two armies face to face they actually form parallel lines.

Comment: Speaking of armies - in many languages the verb _fight_ can be followed by _with_ and _against_ with the same meaning (with the former leading sometimes to fun ambiguities: _-Edna! Fight you with us on the morrow? -Oh, goodness, no. I thought I'd fight with the enemy._)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is pretty logical: to go against someone or something, you must first go towards it.
For example, in Swedish both meanings are expressed with the same  preposition *mot*:

- *ett tåg mot Stockholm* = a train to Stockholm
- *kampen mot rasism* = the fight against racism
- *vända sig mot solen* = to turn towards the sun
- *vända sig mot fienden* = to turn against the enemy

Comment: And as with the example above, I bet Swedish _mot_ (towards, against,...) is related to German _mit_ (with).

Answer (score -1):

Greek prepositions and the verbal prefixes derived from them are a bit mysterious as their various meanings are often very heterogenous. My assumption is that in some prepositions several words have flowed together, which is easily possible if we consider the fact that Old Greek is not a homogeneous language but a side-by-side of various dialects which can influence each other.